Closure of sets in included point topology
I was wondering if the closure of a set $A \subseteq X$ in the included point topology with respect to some point $p$ is the following:

$\bar A = A$ if $A$ doesn't include $p$ (as then the complement of $A$ would be open. I think this is right)
$\bar A = X$ if $A$ includes $p$. This would be because every set including $p$ is open, and the only set containing $p$ which is also closed is the whole space.
But I'm not sure about that last part; I think it's right since if a set containing $p$ was closed, its complement would have to be empty (because it can't include $p$).

This is for a problem where I have to give an example of a compact set with non compact closure (so I thought I could take an open set in this topology and have the whole space not be compact).
Thanks in advance.

Yes, this is all true. (And yes, the included point topology is not compact if the set is infinite, so ${p}$ would be a compact set with non-compact closure.)

What do you mean by "with respect to some point $p?$"

By definition, given a set $X$ and a point $p\in X,$ the included point topology on $X$ with respect to $p$ is the collection $\mathcal T$ of subsets of $X$ such that $U\in\mathcal T$ if and only if $U=\emptyset$ or $p\in U.$
Considering complements gives us the closed sets. Namely, as subset $C$ of $X$ is closed if and only if $C=X$ or $p\notin C.$
Hence, as you say, if $A$ is a non-empty open set (that is, if $p\in A\subseteq X$), then the only closed superset is $X,$ and so $A$ is dense in $X.$
As long as $X$ is a set with a countably-infinite subset, then you can prove it isn't compact in the included point topology. In fact, as long as $p\in A\subseteq X,$ then the included point topology on $A$ with respect to the point $p$ is the same as the subspace topology of $A$ in $X,$ so if such a set $A$ has a countably-infinite subset, then it will not be compact. This limits your choices for compact open sets $A$ to finite subsets of $X,$ and so picking any such $A$ with $p\in A$ will do the trick.

Why to write "$X$ is a set with a countably-infinite subset" instead of "$X$ is infinite"?

Because it matters which version of "infinite" one is using. For example, if $X$ is an amorphous set, then it's infinite in the sense that there is no injection $X\to\Bbb N,$ but $X$ has no countably-infinite subsets, and is in fact compact under the included point topology.

The standard setting in most Mathematics is working with $ZFC$ where both version of infinite are equivalent, so I think it's confusing using that wording without making any reference to the Axiom of Choice.

Certainly that's the norm, but even in $\mathsf{ZFC},$ it matters which property of infinitude one uses in order to prove something, hence my inclusion of that property without worrying about whether Choice was being assumed.

Ok, that's a good point.
